# With initializer list program working fine, but not when directly assigned

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++, while writing code to implement a smart pointer I came across this problem and having some confusion.

```
template<typename T> class SP
{
    T* pData;
    public:
    SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue)
    {
   //     pValue = pData;
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *pData;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        return pData;
    }
};

class Shape
{
    float length;
    float breadth;
    float area;
    public:
    Shape()
    { }
    Shape(float i,float j)
    {
        length = i;
        breadth = j;
        cout<<"Constructor called\n";
        cout<<length<<breadth<<endl;
    }
    void calculateArea()
    {
        area = length * breadth;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Lenght = "<<length<<endl;
        cout<<"Breadth = "<<breadth<<endl;
        cout<<"Area = "<<area<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SP<Shape> ptr(new Shape(1.1,2.2));
    ptr->calculateArea();
    ptr->display();
    return 0;
}
```

If I directly assign `pValue = pData;` I am seeing a memory fault where as when using the initializer the program is working fine.

```
SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue)
```

Please help me understand how is the programming running fine when initializer list is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've swapped the assignment around.

Instead of

```
pValue = pData;
```

You want to do

```
pData = pValue;
```

Comment: Thanks nos, missed that part.Please help me understand how is initializer list different from direct assignment? Is there any specific where we should use initailizer list

Comment: Yes, absolutely! For example, if you initialize a class with ``const`` variables, you need to use the member initialization list in order to initialize the const variables. Additionally, I believe the compiler optimizes construction better with member initialization lists; in other words, use them.